# how do I install pdsh on centos 6?

Tags: centos, virtualization, bash, virtualbox, hadoop

I'm following a [tutorial](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.0/bk_using_Ambari_book/content/ambari-chap1-2.html) on how to configure a centos machine to be a node in a hadoop cluster for [HortonWorks](http://www.hortonworks.com). I'm doing this on a virtual machine on VirtualBox.

Sadly, since I am a linux beginner, I am stuck on some very basic steps:

```
 2.4. Software Requirements

On each of your hosts:

yum

rpm

scp

curl

wget

pdsh
```

I know that all of the above are installed because when I type them in the terminal, something is returned besides *bad command or file name*.

However, when i type `pdsh`, I am getting the *bad command...*

I've googled dozens of websites, and there's no clear direction on **how to install pdsh**?

Comment: If you truly just need pdsh, you can "yum install pdsh". You can also run "rpm -qa | grep pdsh" to see if it's on your system and once it is, what version it is.

Comment: @Eric thank you but im getting, syntax error near unexpected token '('

Comment: im running su root yum install pdsh

Comment: @Eric the rpm -qa returned nothing btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this first:

```
yum update
```

Say yes to all updates, later run:

```
rpm -Uvh http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/GA/ambari-1.x-1.el6.noarch.rpm
```

And:

```
yum install pdsh
```

If this commands retrieve errors, copy from terminal and paste here

Comment: thanks so much, is there a way to copy from host system to VM? the vm is centos. ive already installed the guest additions

Comment: bythe way, after running yum update, im getting the same error: import command not found, try command not found, except command not found , syntax error near token...

Comment: thanks!! i just did su, and then entered password, and then i did what you said and it worked!

Comment: For the copy and paste from host system to VM guest's I recommend to use putty (if you use windows) directly to the server, is more easy.

Comment: I don't remember if I can put links here but open google and search for putty, download in a windows machine, it's an executable no install is require if You just download putty. Putty is an remote terminal application for windows (basically), you can save your sessions to use later, search a complete tutorial for putty, but basically You just have to put the ip address of the server and press open, then insert credentials.

Answer (score 2):

For those whom are not using Hadoop, but looking for just pdsh, it can be obtained in the [Fedora EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).  The repository can be enabled on CentOS / RHEL 6 by running...

```
wget http://mirrors.mit.edu/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install pdsh
```

Personally, the EPEL is the one of the few trusted repos I'll venture out to for a CentOS / Redhat Enterprise Linux server.  I've also shortened the link for you if you have to manually type it in the console of the VM.

```
wget http://goo.gl/2GWMof
```